# Kubernetes ubuntu bare metal to add new node to cluster

Tags: kubernetes

im using ubuntu bare metal kube-up script to build my cluster. Im wondering what's the recommended way to add a new node(minion) to the cluster. Can we use the util.sh's `provision-minions` function to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your question better. Do you mean to add a node to the cluster on the fly?

Comment: I have a running cluster and want to add a new node (vm) to it

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow up. I haven't tried it myself, but I guess to add a node, you need to start the kubelet and kube-proxy on your new node, you can take a look at `start_kubelet` and `start_kubeproxy` functions in hack/local-up-cluster.sh. And you need to make sure the networking requirement is met: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/networking.md#how-to-achieve-this